# magento upgrade error 1075 incorrect table definition

Tags: upgrade

when I execute "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"

I got this error:
 enter code hereCache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:

/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Amazon
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Composer
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/DOMDocumentFactory.php
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Dotdigitalgroup
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Klarna
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/MSP
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Magento
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Symfony
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Temando
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Vertex
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/code/Yotpo
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/metadata/adminhtml.php
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/metadata/crontab.php
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/metadata/frontend.php
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/metadata/global.php
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/metadata/graphql.php
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/metadata/interception.php
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/metadata/webapi_rest.php
/var/www/magento-ci/generated/metadata/webapi_soap.php

Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key, query was: ALTER TABLE `cms_block` MODIFY COLUMN `block_id` smallint(6)  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Entity ID", DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`block_id`)

Is there anybody know the reason? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you imported any existing DB before executing upgrade command

Comment: same issue faced. Yes after data migration i ran setup:upgrade and got this error.

Comment: i have same issue, :((

Comment: Please share solution here how to fixed this issue. I have facing same issue.

Comment: I have been facing the same issue can any one advise how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason why its happend.

You need to you use fresh database and then setup:upgrade.